# T-SQL Conditional 'WHERE' Clause and 'IN' Clause to include all the keys in the result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, in-clause

I have a two tables: `Tag` and `History`, where `Tag` Table stores the information about all the `TagName`'s and `History` Table stores real-time data received from an inverter.

Now, I have 14 different sites from which I get the real-time date of the inverters, as shown below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TagName
FROM History
WHERE TagName LIKE '%DailykWh'
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tAo4.png)

I am using this same query to find the `SUM()` of the `Value` column by Grouping them with the TagName

```
SELECT
    TagName,
    SUM (Value) Monthly
FROM
    History h1
WHERE
    TagName IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            h2.TagName
        FROM 
            History h2
        WHERE
            h2.TagName LIKE '%DailykWh'
    ) AND 
    DateTime BETWEEN '2020-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-11-08 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
    TagName
ORDER BY
    TagName
```

But the result includes only the first TagName and not all the TagNames as shown below.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p4Jj.png)

If I hardcode all the TagNames in the subquery, then I am getting the results from all the sites. I don't want to hardcode them, is there any other way to include all the sites in the query results?

I am new to T-SQL, I think there maybe something else that I can use instead of the `IN` clause, but I don't know which one. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What type is TagName column - char or varchar? This can make difference for LIKE operator.

Comment: @Arvo the TagName columns is 'nvarchar' datatype.

Comment: @Sai, hello, are you sure all Value  fields contain not-null data?

Comment: Why do you need a subquery with IN containing values from the same table? Is this not exactly the same as using `h1.TagName LIKE '%DailykWh'` in the WHERE clause? But it seems you have few rows matching your date filter. Run some simple queries to see if there are any rows for more than one tag for that period.

Comment: @SMor your solution has worked well for me. I replaced the subquery with additional condition in the WHERE clause like you mentioned, and with the ```DateTime``` column I am able to get the results I want. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using join

```
SELECT
    t.TagName,
    SUM (Value) Monthly
FROM
    Tag t left join History h on h.tagname=t.tagname
WHERE t.TagName LIKE '%DailykWh'
group by 
    t.TagName
ORDER BY
    t.TagName
```

Comment: The join is probably unnecessary as well. But it remains a mystery to me why the original query does not yield the expected results, while hardcoding the tag values does.

Answer (score 0):

Not all tags are available in the history table. You can `left join`, so "missing" tags are not filtered out:

```
select t.tagname, sum(h.value) as monthly
from tag t
left join history h on h.tagname = t.tagname
where t.tagname like '%Dailykwh'
group by t.tagname
order by t.tagname
```

This will bring `null` values in `monthly` for missing tags. If you want `0` instead, use `coalesce()`:

```
coalesce(sum(h.value), 0) as monthly
```

Comment: Missing tags in the `Tag` table may indeed be the issue at hand. If all tag values in the `History` table would be available in the `Tag` table as well, it would work fine, I guess. And a join might be unnecessary in that case; all data for the query would be available in the `History` table.

Comment: @BartHofland: yes. That's why "missing" tags seems like the only scenario that makes sense, given the information given in the questin.

Comment: The answers from both @Fahmi and @GMB works fine, thanks! Now, what if I want to add another condition to the 'WHERE' clause, like filtering based on the date? 

```

Comment: @Sai: if it's a condition on `history`, put in the `on` clause of the `left join`.

Comment: I have all the ```Tag``` values in the ```History``` table as well, sorry for not providing that information before.

Comment: ``` SELECT DISTINCT
 TagName
FROM 
 History
WHERE
 TagName LIKE '%DailykWh' ```

This also gives all the required ```Tag``` values I need.

Comment: @GMB I have updated the question by including the DateTime filter as well, but still I cannot get the required results.

Answer (score 0):

From the response given by @SMor, I have tried the following query and it has worked for me.

```
SELECT
    TagName,
    SUM (Value) Monthly
FROM
    History
WHERE
    TagName LIKE '%DailykWh' AND
    DateTime BETWEEN '2020-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-11-10 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
    TagName
ORDER BY
    TagName
```

Thanks everyone for your replies and answers.